# How to use Xamarin in Visual Studio and Mac in the same time

Tags: ios

I have just developed and android app using eclipse and now I want to develope its IOS version. I want to use Visual Studio and C# (I feel pretty much comfortable in these environments).

I read that, to achieve this I can use Xamarine. Everything is OK with configuring Xamarine on Visual Studio and using it in Visual Studio (I understood this part). I couldnt understant the "mac" part. They are saying that in order to build this app I need a mac running in my local network. Unfortunately I have no idea about Mac. Instead of using it in a local network, could I just install it in a Virtual Machine in windows and configure it on that way that I can see this mac from Visual Studio (How can I do this ?! :S).

I am sorry if my question is unclear but I would be greateful if any of you helps me understand these issues and help me develop my first IOS app in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to do iOS development using Xamarin you need a Mac. A Mac will always be required to submit the app to the app store, and the way Xamarin works, you need to use a Mac to create the UI for iOS apps as well.

To get the most of the Xamarin, you ideally would develop your base code using Xamarin and C#, then build separate UI's for both Android and iOS. While your UIs are separate, your base core code is all the same for both apps.

It really does not make sense to have a native Android app all in Java, and then write the entire iOS app in C#. Either stick to completely native apps for both platforms, or use a wrapper like Xamarin for both.

> Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio makes it possible to develop iOS
>   applications on Windows, but you will still need a Mac in order to
>   compile and run the code.
>
> Today, Xamarin.iOS integration in Visual Studio is focused on enabling
>   developers to develop in C#. Xamarin developers who write Xamarin.iOS
>   applications on Windows typically hand-code their user interfaces—or
>   they will need to switch to the Mac to use Xcode (or a beta version of
>   Xamarin’s new iOS Designer) to interactively design an iOS user
>   interface layout.

Comment: @RyanGAs I understood from your answer,I cannot build UI for IOS in Visual Studio using Xamarine right? If so, how can I build UI in mac because as I said I have no idea about mac. Can I install mac in VM in windows and then configure it as part of my local network in order to see it from VS?

Comment: You can build iOS apps in Visual Studio, BUT you still need a Mac to  submit the app. Native iOS apps are built in Xcode (Android's equivalent to eclipse). Xcode has a tool to build UI for iOS apps (called Storyboards). I added some info into my answer from Xamarin. It seems they do have a iOS interface designer now, but you will still need a mac to compile a distribution build & submit your app.

Comment: Well Thank You for this answer. I think I understand now. One last question. Is it necessary to publish my app to app store? I will use it just for my purposes and Im not goin to sell it online or something. With android you can just take the apk file and you can use it in you mobile. No need to publish it to Play Store or anywhere. (maybe not a clever question but I told you that I am new at all with IOS)

Comment: No you can always just run the app in debug mode on your device (or any other local test devices).. no need to submit it to the app store. In fact, Apple wouldn't let you upload a personal app to the apps tore.

Comment: ...but I want to install my app to my IPhone and use it as a normal app. That`s possible right? Thnx again :)

Comment: Yes when you test your app on your iPhone it will run just as it would as if it were in the app store. Note though that you will need to get an Apples developer license, which is $99/year to test your apps on your device (but you can use up to 100 devices)

Comment: Did I understand you right?! I need to get the license to use my app?! I will use this app in 150 devices most probably. Can I want to use it without publishing to App Store and without getting this developer licence?

Comment: If you wish to put your app on some devices (even without publishing to the app store), you will need a developer license.

Comment: hah that`s definitly non sense from Apple. Anyway thank You for everything. I will use jailbrake my phone or simply I will quit my attempt to develop for IOS :)

Answer (score 1):

*"or use a wrapper like Xamarin for both"*
I have discovered the term wrapping is not correct for this product.
Unlike other products (Corona, Phonegap, Titanium, ...) that wrap up in a common, genericized library, Xamarin compiles at core level with no penalty. It is 100% native. All functionality in all it's supported platforms is 100% available and not watered down.

Wrappers can be faster to program in, in theory, but when you factor in the time you will spend looking for workarounds for the one piece of functionality that is available natively but not in your wrapper library. When you factor in the constant bugs because wrapping for 3 or more platforms is a constantly moving target and you can't count on it working from day to day. 
When you factor all those things in, writing native in c# for all platforms is the better option.
I tried them all, and xamarin was my last choice as I was distracted chasing that perfect golden goose wrapper product.